# What's wrong with this proof that all linear endomorphisms only have real eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f$ be an endomorphism in the real vector space $V$.

Let $\lambda=a+ib$ be an eigenvalue for $f$. We're going to show that $b=0$.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector relative to $a+ib$. Then

$f(v)=(a+ib)v=av+ibv$.

Since $f$ is in a real vector space, both $v$ and $f(v)$ must be real vectors, so all their components are real. In other words, $ibv=0$.

But $v \neq 0$, so $ib=0$ and $b=0$.

---

The only part that seems suspicious to me is when I say that $(a+ib)v=av+ibv$, because we know this distributive property holds for real scalars, being in a real vector space, and not necessarily for complex scalars - for all we know it doesn't even make sense to consider the object $(a+ib)v$.

Comment: Your suspicions should be followed...

Comment: How can an eigenvalue in a real vector space be non-real?

Comment: @user160738 take a look at Fred's answer.

Comment: If the field is the reals in the first place, then to define $\lambda v$, the element $\lambda$ should've been in $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place no?

Answer (score 3):

Example: Let $V= \mathbb R^2$ and let $f$ be given by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $ \pm i$. There is no corresponding eigenvectors $v$ such that $v$ and $f(v)$ are elements of $ \mathbb R^2$ ......

Comment: So, I mean, are non-real eigenvalues only "formal" eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a ***real*** vector space, the expression $\color{red}{(a+ib)\mathbf{v}}$ is simply undefined — there are no complex scalars in a real vector space. So from that point on, your "proof" is meaningless, unfortunately.

To make this meaningful, we can construct the ***complexification*** $V^{\mathbb{C}}$ of the real vector space $V$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). Then in $V^{\mathbb{C}}$, the expression $(a+ib)\mathbf{v}$ is fine, but it doesn't lead to any contradiction, as nothing has to be real anymore (so to speak).

Often, it seems pretty natural to involve complex eigenvalues even when $V$ is a real vector space. For example, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then any linear transformation $f:V\to V$ can be represented with a square matrix, and its characteristic polynomial may have complex roots. But once these complex roots are introduced, we're effectively talking about the complexification $V^{\mathbb{C}}$, even if the author carelessly forgets to mention that.